# I have a query of related records for account

Tags: apex, soql

```
String s1 = 'SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts), (SELECT Id FROM Assets), (SELECT Id FROM Cases), (SELECT Id FROM Contracts), (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities), (SELECT Id FROM orders), (SELECT Id FROM Events), (SELECT Id FROM Positions__r) FROM Account WHERE Id = 0012800000mjhO3';
```

For this I used:

```
System.Debug(Database.query(s1));
```

But it's giving me only the `Account` `Id`.

**Log:**

> 19:10:38:086 USER_DEBUG [79]|DEBUG|(Account:{Id=0012800000mjhO3AAI})

Is there any other way to get the actual output?

Comment: I used database.query(s1);

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? All you're doing is creating a `String`, assigning what is a query to it and debugging said `String`?

Comment: I have edited my question sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I'm guessing with your query, you're trying to get the related records?

Assuming you're using the following `String`:

```
String s1 = 'select id, (select id from contacts), (select id from Assets), (select id from cases), (select id from Contracts), (select id from Opportunities), (select id from orders), (select id from events), (select id from Positions__r)  from account where id=0012800000mjhO3';
```

And querying for it like so:

```
for (Account acc : Database.query(s1)) {
  [...]
}
```

You can access subqueries like so:

```
List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>(); // Create a list to hold Contacts
List<Asset> assetList = new List<Asset>(); // Create a list to hold Assets
// Add more lists as required

for (Account acc : Database.query(s1)) { // Loop through the Account(s)
  for (Contact con : acc.Contacts) { // Foreach Account, loop through Contacts as a Contact record
    contactList.add(con); // Add to list
  }

  for (Asset ass : acc.Assets) { // Foreach Account, loop through Assets as an Asset record
    assetList.add(ass); // Add to list
  }

  // And so on...
}
```

If you're looking just to debug the raw output, you'd still need to assign your query to an `Account`.

```
List<Account> accountList = Database.query(s1);

System.debug('@@@@@ The List: ' + accountList);
```